How to allow download but not edit
This seems to be a basic question but I can't find the answer:
How to allow users to download documents but not edit them?
The user might, for example, download a document and edit their own version, and then upload that, but it would have to have a different file name or go to a different location. But I don't want everyone editing the original document.

Grant "Read" access from where they will download the files. Also, they will need "Contribute" or "Edit" access where they will uploading the documents after editing them locally.
